# Have a webpart hide its self, if the user doesn't have proper permission

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, web-parts

If the user creates a web part page in SharePoint and then adds one of my custom web parts to it, I would like to completely hide a web part depending on a particular users permissions.

For example, I have a reporting web part some users have access to reports and some don't, I don't even want some users to know that reports exist.

I have a custom security API that use to determine if security is allowed or denied, 
I would love to say:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
        bool allowed = PermissionServices.IsAllowed("Reports");
        if (!allowed) {
             this.Hide(); 
             // Where 'this' is the web part
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

I don't control the page code so it has to be in the web part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to look into [Audience Targeting](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/michael/archive/2009/04/05/webparts-and-audiences-part-1-show-or-hide-a-web-part-based-on-audiences.aspx).

Basically audience targeting allows you to customize a page based on the group of the person viewing it, so that a manager will go to "home.aspx" and see a top-sheet results WebPart that includes some statistics, but if a regular developer logs on to the same page, the WebPart won't appear.

You should be careful about confusing [Audiences and Permissions](http://blog.solanite.com/keith/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=11564265-6153-4557-aee2-72d1f62fa4c1&ID=9). Audience targeting does NOT change the permissions of the users involved.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Kirk for pointing out that audience targeting only works in MOSS and not WSS.

Comment: Note that audiences are only available with MOSS and not with WSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do your permissions check within your custom WebPart's `Render()` method. If the user doesn't have the permissions, just don't render anything.

Comment: The outer shell (Chrome) will still be rendered, and the user will still see some aspect of the webpart.

Comment: That's a valid point, if you display the chrome. I was assuming you'd set the Chrome type to "None." If you did that, the user wouldn't have to see anything at all.